# Paper, Rock & Scissors game.(Beginner level)

Tags: python-2.7

**When I entered 4 as my maximum point limit, the code ends the loop at 5. I couldn't get it why**

```
import random

p=0
x = int(raw_input("How many points are required for a win? "))
while p<=x:
     y = raw_input("Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (s)cissors? ")
     z1 = ('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors')
     z = random.choice(z1)
     if y=='r':
          print "Human: Rock  Computer: " + z
          if z=='Rock':
               print "A draw"
          if z=='Paper':
               print "Computer wins!"
          if z=='Scissors':
               print "Human wins!"
               p +=1
               if p ==(x-1):
                   print "Only need one more point!"
               print "Your score is: " + str(p)

     elif y=='p':
          print "Human: Paper Computer: " + z
          if z=='Paper':
               print "A draw"
          if z=='Rock':
               print "Human wins!"
               p +=1
               if p==(x-1):
                   print "Only need one more point!"
               print "Your score is: " + str(p)
          if z=='Scissors':
               print "Computer wins!"

     elif y=='s':
          print "Human: Scissors Coputer: " + z
          if z=='Scissors':
               print "A draw"
          if z=='Paper':
               print "Human wins!"
               p +=1
               if p==(x-1):
                   print "Only need one more point!"
               print "Your score is: " + str(p)
          if z=='Rock':
               print "Computer wins!"
```

**Output:**
Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!
How many points are required for a win? 4
Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (s)cissors? r
Human: Rock  Computer: Paper
Computer wins!
Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (s)cissors? r
Human: Rock  Computer: Rock
A draw
Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (s)cissors? r
Human: Rock  Computer: Rock
A draw
Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (s)cissors? r
Human: Rock  Computer: Scissors
Human wins!
Your score is: 1
Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (s)cissors? r
Human: Rock  Computer: Paper
Computer wins!
Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (s)cissors? r
Human: Rock  Computer: Scissors
Human wins!
Your score is: 2
Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (s)cissors? r
Human: Rock  Computer: Scissors
Human wins!
Only need one more point!
Your score is: 3
Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (s)cissors? r
Human: Rock  Computer: Scissors
Human wins!
Your score is: 4
Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (s)cissors? r
Human: Rock  Computer: Scissors
Human wins!
Your score is: 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop condition is `p<=x`, which means that if `p` equals `x` — i.e., if the human has exactly the required number of points — the loop will run again.  Change it to `while p<x:`.